# iOS static library and Core Graphics error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics

This is the error I get while trying to make a static iOS library with common drawing methods.

I created a new static library project and add two new files Painter.h and Painter.m.

Here is the code :

Painter.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
CGRect rectFor1PxStroke(CGRect rect);
```

Painter.m

```
#import "Painter.h"
CGRect rectFor1PxStroke(CGRect rect) {
    return CGRectMake(rect.origin.x + 0.5, 
                      rect.origin.y + 0.5, 
                      rect.size.width - 1, 
                      rect.size.height - 1);
}
```

If I build the solution I get the following the error :

```
./Painter.h:4:0 ./Painter.h:4: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'rectFor1PxStroke'
```

If I set this file in a classic application project, I have no problem to build and run.

Any idea about this problem ?

Comment: Do you really have #import? Or is it import? It needs to be #import

Comment: Sorry, this is a mistake while copying the code. I do have #import.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- <strike>add `extern` in front of the header file declaration.</strike> No need.
- make sure that your imports have picked up the CoreGraphics header that defines CGRect.

Comment: That's it. I just added the import for CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h.

Comment: Add `extern` in front of the header file declaration?